# One-sampled t-Test: large Cohen's d and large p value (is there a statisctical error?)

Tags: p-value, cohens-d

The p-value from a t-test I have run is unexpectedly large, considering Cohen's d.

I calculated the one-sample t-test in RStudio for the following hypothesis:

H2: For athletes who have already reached their performance peak, the prevention focus is more frequent than the promotion focus.

I used the variable PeakJaNein for the performance peak and the variable Nettohoffnung for prevention and promotion focus.
(variable Nettohoffnung explained: values below zero represent prevention focus and values above zero represent promotion focus)

First, I had to convert the variable PeakJaNein which included people who reached their performance peak (=1) and people who did not reach their performance peak jet (=2). Since I'm only testing for people who reached their peak, I did the following:

```
data_subset <- neu_ba_data[(neu_ba_data$PeakJaNein==1),
                          data_subset = complete.cases(final), ]

dplyr::count(data_subset, data_subset$PeakJaNein)
# Peak reached (1) = 22N
# Peak not reached (NA) = 13
```

Then converted the variable to a factor and did a one-sample t-test. Since the prevention focus is negative (below zero), I tested "less".
(variable Nettohoffnung explained: values below zero mean prevention focus and values above zero represent promotion focus)

```
describe(data_subset$Nettohoffnung)
#mean=6.32; SD=4.02, n=22

#data_subset: PeakJaNein to factor
data_subset$PeakJaNein = as.factor(data_subset$PeakJaNein)

#one sample t-Test
t.test(data_subset$Nettohoffnung, mu=0, alternative = "less", conf.level = 0.95)
#results of the t-Test:
#t-statistic: 7.3783 
#df 21 
#95% KI[-Inf, 7.791679]
#p=1 

#cohens D
lsr::cohensD(data_subset$Nettohoffnung, mu=0)
#cohensD=1.573068
```

I think there is something wrong with the p-value in the one-sample t-test of H2. With such a large Cohen's d (d = 1.57), the p-value should not be p = 1 even with an n = 22.

Did I maybe calculate Cohen's d wrong? I tried including alternative = "less" in my argument, but R gave me the following error message:

```
Error in lsr::cohensD(data_subset$Nettohoffnung, mu = 0, alternative = "less") : 
  unused argument (alternative = "less")
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your time and help!

Comment: You're testing the null hypothesis that $\mu\geq 0$ versus the alternative hypothesis $\mu<0$. Your observed mean is $6.32$ and the standard deviation is $4.02$. Hence, the $p$-value correctly states that there is absolutely no evidence against the null hypothesis because a mean of $6.32$ is not uncommon if the null hypothesis were true. Cohen's $d$ on the other hand is simply $6.32/4.02$ and it measures how many SDs from $0$ the mean is, in any direction.

Comment: Cohen's *d* assesses effect size.  It was intended to use as an *assumption* for designing experiments and to help interpret observational results.  The p-value is a measure of *the degree to which your data are consistent with a zero effect size.*  That's all.  Cohen's *d* and p-values are different things and are not comparable.  The amount of data does not affect the true Cohen's *d* but profoundly influences the p-value.

Comment: Thank you, helped a lot!